# Textformfiled flutter: prefix and suffix not in line with the content

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textinputfield

The textformfiled i want

[image]

and My textformfield now

[image]

I'm trying create a search field like this.(attach this link) but the suffix, prefix icon not align with content

I am also attaching the code that I am using for this TextFormfield:

```
 Container(
            height: 35,
            width: Get.width - 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: backgroundColor.withOpacity(.8),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15, bottom: 10, top: 10, right: 15),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Search',
                prefix: IconButton(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/icons/back.png',
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => toast(content: 'back action'),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                suffix: IconButton(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/icons/plus_circle.png',
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => toast(content: 'clear action'),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CupertinoSearchTextField` and modify the way it as you like. If it doesnt satisfy, you can choose row over prefix and suffix alignment. Here are three looks and code.

[image]

**[CupertinoSearchTextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSearchTextField-class.html)**

```dart
child: CupertinoSearchTextField(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  // decoration: BoxDecoration(
  //   color: Colors.grey,
  //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  // ),
  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
),
```

Using Row

```dart
Container(
  width: 400,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  ),
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      IconButton(
        iconSize: 16,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.ads_click,
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'Search',
          isDense: true,
        ),
      )),
      IconButton(
        iconSize: 16,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.ads_click,
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Using Prefix and suffix

```dart
Container(
width: 400,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.grey,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
),
child: TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Search',
    isDense: true,
    prefix: IconButton(
      iconSize: 16,
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.ads_click,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    ),
    suffix: IconButton(
      iconSize: 16,
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
      icon: Icon(Icons.ads_click),
      onPressed: () {},
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
    ),
  ),
),
),
```

IF you need to change size, provide height and width(if needed wrapped with SizedBox)

Comment: thank for your solution. i'm using row. it's help me

Comment: Glad to help, You can also check [SearchDelegate-class.html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html)

Comment: i voted for you but i got message "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.". sorry my friend

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the icon in a column widget and give mainAxisAlignment center

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   children:[ Icon(),]
  )
```

This will bring the icon to the center of the text field